# Saving information from a question

Tags: discussion

If a question is closed and people keep commenting on it, How do you keep the question preserved so you can still see the comments answers for offline reading?

Does the question and the comments get deleted once closed? If you bookmarked the question do you lose your bookmark?

If I asked the question and it’s closed would it still show up in my history on my profile page where I can access it at anytime?

Comment: These should answer your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/282094 - but I agree it's not clear (that doesn't prevent them from being duplicates, it only means that they may need improvement). - Short answer: Closed and Deleted are different.

Comment: @Rob Yea I'm new and have had like 2 duplicates and 2 closed already I try to find the same question or a question that is like mine but when I go to type the question it gives me similar questions. if they don't match I ask the question. then people that have been here longer find multiple questions and answers. is there a better way to search on stack exchange then the regular search button. just wondering so I can get better at this site. Thanks

Comment: [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) - also, Google with the `site:` operaor

Answer (score 7):

Closing doesn't remove comments. And you can still post comments on them. This is a pretty important feature, because that's how we give OP advice on how to improve the post so that it can be reopened. However, be aware that comments are supposed to be temporary. They are often removed when no longer relevant. Either by the commenter or by a moderator. Closed questions can still be seen by everyone.

Deleting does not remove comments either. However, you need 10k rep to view deleted questions, except for your own. And you cannot post comments on deleted questions.

Comment: One minor clarification is that you can always view your own deleted questions. You only need to have at least 10K in reputation to view *other* members' deleted questions.

Comment: Who removes the comments if they are not needed anymore? also the duplicate/closed question I'm talking about has a lot of information like links to helpful questions within stack exchange. who determines if the comment isn't relevant anymore and then it gets deleted?

Comment: [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/1017231)

Comment: @Jcb - The author of the comment or a moderator after it’s been flagged

Answer (score 4):

If you’re looking simply for a way to preserve the current state of a question so you can refer to it offline, you may find [Stack Printer](https://stackapps.com/q/179) helpful.

> StackPrinter is a website that pulls the main details of a given question, all its answers, comments and votes formatting them in a simple essential printable view.

Comment: I was going over my questions and realized that this answer was here since 2021 and never had a reply to it. Just checked out Stack Printer and its very nice. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a snapshot of a page - there's a few offsite resources that do a good job at it. The [internet archive](https://web.archive.org) is the 'famous' one, and does have a nice calendar view , but I'm also reasonably fond of [archive.today](https://archive.is)

Any of these will let you take a point of time snapshot of a post.

Its also worth remembering that if its your question, or you have an answer to the question, or are a 10k rep user, you can see deleted content.

Comment: People can request that pages be removed from Internet Archive, so this is not as good a solution as getting the question formatted as a single page and saving it yourself in all situations.

Comment: In theory, sure. I mean lots of modern browsers to full page screenshots and let you save pages statically too? I didn't want to cover ground that was in your answer :D

Comment: I just meant it as a caveat, not as disagreement. I think it would be pretty rare that the typical SE question would get removed.  I have seen pages removed though. *shrug* I’m an engineer. Pointing out potential issues in solutions is part of what I do all day :)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I tried to use this the other day when you said it. The question I was trying to archive had about 10 comments or more. When I went to archive it kept showing the comments as collapsed. I even uncollapsed all comments and tried to take the snapshot and it didn’t. Sucks I know